Identify an IC labeled LB21
What is this IC?
Trying to find a datasheet for it. Best I can make out from markings is:
LB 21 

Package: SOT-89-3


It is a LM317LIPK from Texas Instruments (marking "LB", "21" is a datecode).
Picture from lcsc:


looks like that but its 21 not 84

same component, different date of manufacturing (date code)
